# Using Sqlite Data Provider from EntLibContrib and DAAB EntLib 5.0

Tags: sqlite, enterprise-library

is it possible to use [SQLite Data Provider](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SQLiteDataProvider41&referringTitle=Home) from [EntLibContrib 4.1](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/) in with EntLib 5.0? I'm not familiar with EntLib 4.x, I just started using EntLib 5.0 and don't know whether differences between them are severe or not to use data provider from EntLib 4.1 for EntLib 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you were to recompile EntLibContrib from source, updating the dependencies to Enterprise Library.  It would probably be less work to just use use Enterprise Library 4.1, unless there is a specific feature of 5.0 you absolutely can't live without.

Update:
Recompiling from source seems like a no go as the interface IDatabaseAssembler and DatabaseAssembler attribute was removed in Enterprise Library 5.0 when they moved to a dependency injection pattern.

Comment: I've tried using EntLib 4.1, and I don't like DAAB from 4.1, because it lacks of parameter mappers and output mappers, I like them most of all in EntLib 5.0 DAAB, though they are not ideal.

Comment: I hear you.  I was looking for the same exact thing, I guess we'll have to wait until the next release of contrib.  I went ahead and used EntLib 4.1, my scenario wasn't that large anyway and I was creating the commands from some simple code generation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you now can!
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/657233/Enterprise-Library-6-Sqlite-Logging-and-Exceptions
do work with enterprise library 5 & 6